# How can I make three horizontal dots on a letter in plain TeX

Tags: math-mode, plain-tex

How can I make three horizontal dots on a letter in plain TeX?

Answer (score 9):

The `amstex` macros provide this accent.

```
\input amstex

$\dddot{a}$

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Well, not really: this is a *very* long standing bug of `amstex` (and `amsmath`).

Comment: Try `$a+\dot{a}+\ddot{a}+\dddot{a}+\ddddot{a}$`

Answer (score 6):

You can load `amstex` (which is recommended if you do much mathematics), but you have to fix the definitions of `\dddot` (and `\ddddot`):

```
\input amstex

% fix \dddot and \ddddot
\begingroup
\catcode`@=11
\gdef\dddot#1{{\mathop{\kern0pt #1}\limits^{\vbox to-1.4\ex@{\kern-\tw@\ex@
 \hbox{\rm...}\vss}}}}
\gdef\ddddot#1{{\mathop{\kern0pt #1}\limits^{\vbox to-1.4\ex@{\kern-\tw@\ex@
 \hbox{\rm....}\vss}}}}
\endgroup

$a+\dddot{a}+\ddddot{a}$

\bye
```

If you don't want `amstex`, you can use the code with some changes:

```
% define \dddot and \ddddot
\newdimen\ex
\ex.2326ex
\def\dddot#1{{\mathop{\kern0pt #1}\limits^{\vbox to-1.4\ex{\kern-2\ex
 \hbox{\rm...}\vss}}}}
\def\ddddot#1{{\mathop{\kern0pt #1}\limits^{\vbox to-1.4\ex{\kern-2\ex
 \hbox{\rm....}\vss}}}}

$a+\dddot{a}+\ddddot{a}$

\bye
```

[image]